# Load image into UICollectionVIewCell

Tags: ios

Im having problem setting image into UiCollectionViewCell

THis is my code :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/firefox/firstrun/logo.png?2013-06"];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImageView * myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimg"];//set the image

    GLCell *cell = (GLCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.displayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d user number", indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimg"]];


    return cell;
}
```

the string value shows without problem , but cell have no image.

Comment: Are you sure your image file does not have extension? May be it should be changed to `myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimg.JPEG"]' for example?

Comment: don't set myImageView.image it is override the value

Comment: your imageview doesn't add subview of tableview cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/firefox/firstrun/logo.png?2013-06"];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    GLCell *cell = (GLCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.displayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d user number", indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]];
```

Comment: Thanks For the code , but still nothing apear  even after i change the url

Comment: should be check image url valid or not

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adding the myImageView to your cell. Instead of creating your own UIImageView you could just use the UITableViewCell's `imageView` property